# Win 10 Music library Access denied - Old OneDrive-folder

Tags: windows-10, permissions, onedrive

So I had my OneDrive setup on my local C:\ drive and i had my music library in it. I have moved my OneDrive to an SD-Card so to free up some space. However there is still a folder in **C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Music** and I can't delete it.
I have tried:

Take Ownership (cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" /r /d y && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /t)

Set advanced Permissions in 'Properties' [Image 1 - Properties and Adanced Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhHqo.png)
[Image 2 - After clicking 'change'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNT8i.png)

And I've tried simple delete commands through powershell

Edit: [Image: Powershell dir command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh3L6.png)

How can I delete this weird folder?

Comment: The folder may still be opened by the application. Use [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to find if that's the case (binoculars icon). You may also boot in Safe mode and delete it there.

Comment: Wow okay so apparently **Spotify** was holding on to that folder, which makes sense because It was supposed to import local files. Thank you very much!
If you post this as an Answer I'd Accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder may still be opened by some application.

Use
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
to find if that's the case (using the binoculars icon).

Any application that is found can be either configured differently or uninstalled.

Stubborn cases can usually be deleted when booting in Safe mode to avoid all
third-party products from running.